# Is it OK for a provider to update resource ID on an update()

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

*Context*: I'm implementing a Terraform Provider (see https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/providers/provider-setup).

Is it OK for a provider to edit resource ID in an update()? In other words, to call `d.SetID()`?

I did a quick search and I don't think there're a lot of TF Providers that do it (they call `d.SetID()` in create() / read() only) but I wonder are there any downsides / limitations around that (from user's perspective, resource has still got `resource_foo.bar` reference so changing internal ID might be OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Terraform Core's perspective there is nothing special about the `id` attribute and the rules for changing it are just the same as for any other attribute.

Unfortunately, the old Terraform SDK (SDKv2) *does* treat this attribute as special, because it overloads it to use as a signal for whether the object exists at all, and therefore wraps this special setter `d.SetId` around it instead of using the normal `d.Set` API.

Because of this, it is generally *not* safe to change the ID during an `Update` function when using SDKv2. The rest of this answer includes some more detail about why, but if the answer "no" is enough for you then feel free to skip the rest.

---

Terraform Core gives the old SDK some extra latitude in its implementation of the provider protocol because that SDK was originally designed for very old versions of Terraform (Terraform v0.11 and earlier), so changing `id` during update won't cause an error but it *will* cause Terraform to emit a warning to its internal logs, which you can see if you run Terraform with the environment variable `TF_LOG=warn`.

The warning will be something like this:

> [WARN] Provider `registry.terraform.io/example/example` produced an unexpected new value for `example_something.foo`, but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
>
> The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
>
> - .id: was `"old value"`, but now `"new value"`

If any other resource in the configuration includes a reference to `example_something.foo.id` then it will appear to Terraform that the plan for that resource has changed between plan and apply, thereby causing an example of the sort of "confusing errors from downstream operations" that warning speaks of:

```
resource "something_else" "example" {
  foo = example_something.foo.id
}
```

```
Error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan

When expanding the plan for something_else.example to include
new values learned so far during apply, provider
registry.terraform.io/something/something produced an invalid
new value for .foo: was "old value", now "new value".

This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in
the provider's own issue tracker.
```

Because Terraform Core tried to tolerate the invalid answer from the first provider, the problem ended up being blamed on the second provider instead. This would therefore cause bug report noise for developers of other providers, and so is best avoided.

---

The newer [Terraform Plugin Framework](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework) is designed around modern Terraform and doesn't have all the legacy limitations of SDKv2, so for providers written using that framework the `id` attribute is not special and follows the same rules as for any other attribute, just like Terraform Core.

The rules for changing an attribute during apply are:

1. During the planning step you must either set the attribute to its new value immediately or you must mark it as unknown so that Terraform will show it as `(known after apply)` in the plan. You can achieve this using the [Plan Modification](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification) features of the framework.
2. During the apply step a provider is allowed to choose any value for an attribute that was marked as unknown during the planning step, but is required to return *exactly the same value* if the attribute was not marked as unknown during the planning step.

The old SDK is unable to follow these rules because it offers no way to mark the `id` attribute as unknown during planning. The only way to successfully change the ID of an object after it was already created would be to change the ID to the concrete new value during the *planning* phase, by implementing a `CustomizeDiff` function. This would be possible only if the configuration includes enough information to already know what the ID will be before reaching the apply step.